# Programmatically create map from google map tiles?

Tags: image, google-maps

As inspiration from Google's [8-bit google maps](http://maps.google.com/?t=8&utm_campaign=8bit&utm_source=yt) April Fool's joke, I'm trying to put a program together that can create a world map image from the 8-bit tiles.  Does anyone have a good method to programmatically create an image from a map tile source?  Also, is this even possible/legal with Google map tiles, or would I be violating some type of license?

Any point in the right direction or personal experience recommendation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a decent article about how google map tiles work here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14793/How-Google-Map-Works

The key would be to use the algorithm that is mentioned within the article to retrieve a map tile based on a specific lat/lng pair, and then iterate through all of the possible combinations.

It is probably ok to do, as long as you don't exceed the number of requests, and don't use the map for commercial/evil purposes.

Comment: SWEET this article pointed me in the right direction.  If anyone else is looking for the URL format of the 8-bit map tiles, here's a sample:  http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=8bit,m@129&hl=ru&x=59&y=98&z=8&s=

Answer (score 0):

Google actually got the idea from one of the Bing Maps MVP's who wrote this blog post on how to create an 8-bit map using Bing Maps: http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/creating-the-legend-of-zelda-map-tiles-from-bing-maps-aerial-imagery/